# image does not load from uri after getting string from sqlite db

Tags: java, android

I took an image using the cameraIntent then I saved the string of imageUri to the database. Before I save it in database if I load image in a view using the uri it works but when I get the string uri from database parse it and load it does not display anything it does not give any error too.Why does not it display the image ? Thank You

This is the uri obtained after taking picture.

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requesetcode,int resultcode,Intent data){
  if(data != null ) {
      //Toast.makeText(this, "code " + requesetcode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      super.onActivityResult(requesetcode, resultcode, data);
      Uri imageUri = data.getData();
      if (requesetcode == 0) {
          check = imageUri.toString();
          checkimage.setImageURI(imageUri);
          Toast.makeText(this,imageUri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


      } else {
          customerImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
            cust = imageUri.toString();
      }
  }

}
```

This is how I saved it in the database.

```
db.updateCustomer(custName, compName, phone, address, check, cust, id);
```

This is how I used it later again.

```
info = db.getcustomerInfo(pName);
if(info[5] !=null){
Uri uri = Uri.parse(info[5]);
checkimg.setImageURI(uri);
        Toast.makeText(this,"*"+uri.toString()+"*",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Picasso.with(this).load(uri).into(checkimg);
```

Comment: Do you close your app or clear cache before loading it the second time?

Comment: Also, you said you "used it later again". So could you clarify how much "later" do you use it with respect to when you first uploaded the photo to the database?

Comment: Are you sure that you read the correct column? Can you provide any log of your code?

Comment: Show the values of uri.toString() and uri.getPath() both before and after storing.

Comment: i do not clear the cache and i used it instantly after i saved it in the database. EasyJoin , I toasted the string result from the database it is exactly same.